# Accessing Individual Collection Elements in WiX

Tags: arrays, velo

I’m currently working with a database collection using Wix’s code. Previously, I displayed information using a table that accessed the entire database itself, and using a search function that limited the data. I was able to display items from a certain category using those parameters I put in.

Right now, however, I am trying to put INDIVIDUAL data points and information into text labels using code, but I’m having difficulty. I am unable to work with the database collection in this way, i.e. accessing individual items and information pieces, but I think that I do this by looking at individual indexed elements. I am just not sure of the syntax. Can you help me access these individual collection elements? Thanks.

```
// console.log($w(res).getItems(1, 1)); 
wixData.get("indexResearchers", "university") .then( (results) => { 
    let item = results; 
    //see item below console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 1"); 
    let fieldValue = item.fieldName; 
    console.log(fieldValue); 
    // console.log(item.get('university')); 
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 2"); 
    // console.log(item.items[0]); 
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 3"); 
    console.log(item.items[0].get('university')); 
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 4"); 
} )
```

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Function stuff.... Then this:
   // console.log($w(res).getItems(1, 1));

   wixData.get("indexResearchers", "university")
   
   .then( (results) => {
      let item = results; //see item below
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 1");
    let fieldValue = item.fieldName;
    console.log(fieldValue);
    // console.log(item.get('university'));
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 2");
    // console.log(item.items[0]);
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 3");
    console.log(item.items[0].get('university'));
    console.log("\nAND HEREEEEEEE 4");
     } )

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about getting individual items from a collection.

If using a dataset:

- You can filter the dataset using the UI or [via code](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-dataset.html#setFilter).
- You can also use the [getItems()](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-dataset.html#getItems) or [getCurrentItem()](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-dataset.html#getCurrentItem) functions to get individual items from a dataset.

If using the wix-data API:

- You can use the get() or [query()](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-data.html#query) functions.

If you filter the dataset, you can connect page elements to the dataset using their connect buttons. For all other options, you'll have to populate the page elements using code.